# Django - Easiest way to translate just 1 page

Tags: django, internationalization

I want to translate only 1 page (1 Django template) to 2 different languages.

After reading a bit about Django internationalization, seems quite complex and probably an overkill for my use case (it's just 1 page and not even a public website, just an internal report).

It would be great if I could use the same view for different 2 templates (one template for each language), but I don't know how to do that.

Currently, I'm using something like this to send the info to the template (the list is actually much longer):

```
context = {
'campaigns' : campaigns,
'data_campaigns' : data_campaigns,
'manual_changes' : manual_changes,
'groups_bad' : groups_bad,
}
return render(request, 'english.html', context)
```

It would be great if I could create a "spanish.html" template and just translate the text directly in that template.

Is it possible? Are there better (and not very complex) solutions?

Also, maybe using "context" like this is not a best practice. I'm learning Django, it was the easiest option I found and it works. I'm open to change it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but something like this would be a simple solution:

```py
from django.utils.translation import activate

def your_view(request, language=None):
    if language == 'es':
        activate('es')
        template = 'spanish.html' # may be redundant?
    else:
        template = 'english.html'

    ...
```

You would need to amend your url to accept the language parameter as a string (or choose some other method of distinguishing which language is selected).

Comment: Thanks, but I can't make it work. I tried changing urls.py to accept the language parameter. I already had: path("audit/<custom_id>", views.get, name="get") and I changed it to: path("audit/<custom_id>/<language>", views.get, name="get". But it always loads the default template/language, it doesn't seem to be getting the "es" language parameter if I visit for example http://127.0.0.1:8000/audit/1740/es

Comment: Also, why do I need "from django.utils.translation import activate"? I don't really want to use Django's translation, I just want to load a different template when I put "es" or "en" in the URL.

Comment: Print the `language` parameter in the view to see what is being produced by the URL. You also don't need to use `activate()` if you aren't using Django's translation framework

Comment: OK, thanks! The problem was that I didn't change the render line. Apparently "return render(request, template, context)" is what I needed.